Android 14: This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android
Using Delphi 12.1
I have a customer using a 32bit version of Android 14.
During startup he manages to get into the program, into the Setup screen, but then he gets a big warning "This app isn't compatible with the latest version of Android".
I am using all the default libraries, minSdkVersion="23", and I don't see anything in the Google Android 14 information which would indicate this problem.  Unfortunately I do not have an Android 14 device myself.
I was wondering if it could have anything to do with the new Map system?  At this point in the App the Map was not accessed yet.
The Manifest looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp"
    android:versionCode="1009"
    android:versionName="1.019C"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />

    </queries>
    <application
        android:persistent="False"
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False"
        android:label="SARTrack"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="nz.sartrack.SARTrackApp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="XXXX" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="12451000" />

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />

<service android:name="com.embarcadero.services.SARTrackService" android:exported="false" />

        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="SARTrack"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="SARTrackApp" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->



Note that the problem is specific to Android 14. The App works fine on Android 13 and lower.

@NguyễnMạnhCường Delphi doesn't use Gradle build tool like Android Studio does. Instead Delphi is using its own compiler which is based on LLVM technology.

I managed to get an Android 14 device, and now have the problem pinpointed: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts.  But I have no idea how to fix this in the runtime enviroment I currently use.

The problem was with the registerReceiver for the Broadcast system between the App and its Service.
And interestingly, I was forced to use "RECEIVER_EXPORTED" because otherwise the App would not receive any broadcasts from its own Service!
Final code look now like this:
vFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  for i := 0 to High(Args) do
    vFilter.addAction(Args[i]);
  if TOSVersion.Major >= 13
  then TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(fListener.fReceiver, vFilter,2)
  else TAndroidHelper.context.getApplicationContext.registerReceiver(fListener.fReceiver, vFilter);

where the "2" indicates RECEIVER_EXPORTED. ("4" is "RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED")
